# Implement Wagtail ListBlock module with min/max children

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I'm building a new block type for use in the StreamField. It's called an FAQModule and it should allow a title and 1 or more question/answer pairs.

```py
class FAQBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    headline = blocks.TextBlock(help_text="Enter headline / question")
    text = blocks.TextBlock(help_text="Enter a description / answer ")

class FAQCardsWithListBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    title = blocks.TextBlock(help_text="Enter FAQ title")
    questions = blocks.ListBlock(FAQBlock())

    class Meta:
        label = 'FAQ Block'
        icon = 'help'
```

It works exactly as expected, and looks like this:
[image]

However I want to enforce a min/max number of Q/A blocks. I see that the StreamBlock allows for this but my team and I agree that the interface for the ListBlock implementation is exactly what we want. So I'm working to add a min/max enforcement to our feature based off what's in the [StreamBlock implementation](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/33204be10586128d44156b8a3b91a5cf2c0db4d0/wagtail/core/blocks/stream_block.py#L188-L236). I've gotten it to error on submit, but I can't get the badge to show up in the Content tab, nor can I get the error to show itself in the block.

Does anyone have thoughts on how this might be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

ListBlock has optional `min_num` and `max_num` parameters nowadays. [(Official documentation)](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/streamfield/blocks.html#wagtail.blocks.ListBlock)

In the case of the original question, the solution would look something like:

```py
class FAQCardsWithListBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    questions = blocks.ListBlock(FAQBlock(), min_num=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

i don't have use StreamBlock for the moment, but the InlinePanel have parameters for minimum / maximum item relation.

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/reference/pages/panels.html#inlinepanel

Comment: Oh neat, thanks for the mention. I'll look into InlinePanel!