# How to limit the number of items in a ListBlock?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I want to limit the number of entries a ListBlock can have. I know this is possible in StreamField with `max_num` but I can't see a way to do the same for ListBlocks.

We need to use ListBlocks as they are more user friendly for our users than StreamField.

An example of the code:

```py
class TextQuestionBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
   question_text = ShortcodeRichTextBlock()
   correct_answer = blocks.CharBlock(label="Correct Answer", required=True)
   false_answer = blocks.ListBlock(blocks.CharBlock(label="False Answer(s)", required=True))
```

We want to limit the number of false answers a user can inout

I want to limit the user tro 3 false answers. Currently they can add as many as they like.

Comment: Hi, maybe you can take a look a [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58204856/implement-wagtail-listblock-module-with-min-max-children), it is very similar to yours.